# How to use spread operator together with typescripts utility type `Parameters`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I built a higher order function that caches the result of a function if it is invoked with the same parameters. This is using the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type to return a function with the same signature passing the arguments to the wrapped function.

```js
function memoize<FN extends (...args: any) => Promise<any>>(fn: FN) {
  const cache: Record<string, Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<FN>>>> = {};

  return (...args: Parameters<FN>) => {
    const cacheKey = JSON.stringify(args);

    if (!(cacheKey in cache)) {
      // @ts-ignore
      const promise = fn(...args);
      cache[cacheKey] = promise;
    }

    return cache[cacheKey];
  };
}
```

Without the `ts-ignore` typescript will fail with `Type 'Parameters<FN>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. ts(2488)`. How do I fix this correctly?

The function is used like this:

```js
const cachedFunction = memoize(async (id: string) => fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`))
const resultFromAPI = cachedFunction("1")
const resultFromCache = cachedFunction("1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where `Parameters<FN>` isn't seen as spreadable is considered a bug in TypeScript as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#36874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36874).  This can be worked around by changing the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) from `(...args: any) => ⋯` to `(...args: any[]) => ⋯`:

```
function memoize<FN extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>(fn: FN) {
  const cache: Record<string, Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<FN>>>> = {};

  return (...args: Parameters<FN>) => {
    const cacheKey = JSON.stringify(args);

    if (!(cacheKey in cache)) {
      const promise = fn(...args); // okay
      cache[cacheKey] = promise;
    }

    return cache[cacheKey];
  };
}
```

Still, this is not the recommended approach here.

---

The [`Awaited`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype), [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types are implemented as [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  Inside the body of `memoize()`, the `FN` type is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) type parameter, and so `Parameters<FN>` and `Awaited<ReturnType<FN>>` are *generic conditional types*.  TypeScript is notoriously unable to do much analysis on generic conditional types.  It tends to defer evaluation of them, so inside `memoize()`, the type `Parameters<FN>` is mostly opaque.  Thus when you call `fn(...args)` the compiler can't be sure if `args` is appropriate.  So it either has to report an error all the time or none of the time.

Since `FN` is constrained to `(...args: any[]) => ⋯`, calling `f(...args)` ends up widening `FN` to its constraint, which accepts any arguments at all, and therefore it ends up failing to report an error no matter what.  So `fn(...args)` is accepted, but so is something obviously bad like `fn(123)`:

```
const promise = fn(123); // okay?!!!
```

If you do decide to use this approach, then, you should be very careful.  Generic conditional types are best avoided when possible.

---

Instead of generic conditional types, the recommended approach is to make your function generic not in `FN`, the full function type, but in its argument list `A` and return type `R`:

```
function memoize<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: A) => Promise<R>) {
  const cache: Record<string, Promise<R>> = {};

  return (...args: A) => {
    const cacheKey = JSON.stringify(args);

    if (!(cacheKey in cache)) {
      const promise = fn(...args); // okay
      cache[cacheKey] = promise;
    }

    return cache[cacheKey];
  };
}
```

This compiles cleanly, and the compiler is actually able to understand what you're doing well enough that if you write `fn(123)` you'll get the expected error

```
const promise = fn(123); // error!
//                 ~~~
// Argument of type '[number]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKbLjAXqgGgHgDEA5RVADylTABMBnRACgDpWBDAJwHM6AuRNmACeAbQC6ASkQBeAHyIAChzjIYdVPkFDZsxsDD8SUgN4AoRIggI6US2wgALVPwBKqKxxr4bHGGC4ANIrKqur4AIIA7mwwVF5uUCAcYAAqQgAOGiQ6OjKIxgC+ANym5ogcqInJTKzMnDz8CpxsaFQcdETEslJy+WUWVmA2do6oANKoQnkAUgDKAPLEzD5+XDDAQoz1dBIl-YjrTACEjBD2ThNTfiNOEib7A9a26SFqqHn6LOzcOyUW-4hPgBGABMAGZdogAPRQxBgOBkDjKDhHB43VAiM6jS5iPIvFRvP7-AqlAEVKpILFOTHncaTMRE4qmEmmUCQWAIFDoTA4CJkSjUegCYTiIIuXT6fhfOo-fjhHryJQEsLi+6PIa2KnORBuDxeFb+IJK0IacXyaT5JllclJJDS7ZyhV9AGDYZay4zBZLA1rDZbH67Un-Q6ME7uyYHSm0u7OgGWJ6IfEmj5ge0BorQ2FwADWbCEaOB4MhMMRyLRWpp2PpeNe6iJFhZZMqtvRlYu9MZJRZrs1tJohHA0HgSAtaAw2FQWzoQkgTBgNH4PqdwEqjkYAAMHFAoOk+DCAFZ0BDpAA29lQDjgJ5oqA4zCgGRgVhvzCsyChUDgNDgdChABJjHnAp1zuUwe3KVA6BAE8oEIEJwgUABJPItX7QcOVTAAiIFMIkMCEwqKCYLglQAGFaRQvsB3ZYdGGw3CgA)